# WCF Post Operation Contract returning 400 bad request

Tags: c#, wcf, bad-request

So basically I have an wcf service which should handle POST method an posted data is a url encoded form. this are my appropriate classes

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]  
        Stream Check(RequestObject request);
    }
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public Stream Check(RequestObject request)
    {
        // do some stuff;
        return null; // for brevity
    }
}

[DataContract]
    public class RequestObject
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "KEY")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
```

every time I make a post request to the url with request body being KEY=1234 (or anything) the service returs 400 Bad Request. I tried making the service method parameterless and than it work. I mean it return 200 OK. am I doing something wrong here ? if needed I can provide the web.config

Comment: Is it `Check` or `CheckTransaction`?

Comment: does the name matter? I mean yeah for URL of course but, does it matter here in this case ?

Comment: Well the above code will not compile due to the nature of interface implementation in .NET

Comment: never mind that. I've misspelled the method in class

Answer (score 1):

It seems Service doesn't like your data format. Try to send xml or json.

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) to see format type handling.

Comment: I've tried both json and xml in both cases it worked perfectly.